# The intersection of a and b is a superset of the product when a and b are ideals

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

Let a and b be ideals of a ring A. Define
$$ab=\left\{{\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_jb_j|a_j\in a,b_j \in b,n \in \mathbb{N}}\right\}$$
Prove that $ab$ and $a\cap b$ are ideals of A, and that $a\cap b \supseteq ab$ but they are not necessarily equal.

For the first bit to be proved, I assume it is necessary to simply show the properties of an ideal hold for both $ab$ and $a\cap b$, but how do you show that $a\cap b \supseteq ab$?

Comment: You correctly writ $\supseteq$, but wrongly speak of *subset*.

Comment: The claim in the title was wrong. The union of two ideals is not a subset of the product. Thankfully the question body fixes things. You seem to be asking whether the product is a subset of the intersection. Please review basic set concepts (may be this was an error in translation).

Comment: Apologies, it was a typo. Thought I'd corrected it, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that $a_jb_j\in a$ and $a_jb_j\in b$ for each $j$